# finding old cookies from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

so I was using chrome to do research on subatomic particles and the website got taken down so I'm on my C Drive under the path users username app that a local Google Chrome user data default and there are just a lot of folders and files I was just wondering which one of these files or folders could I open and using what software to read the articles that I have no access to

Comment: Cookies would just be the key/value pairs that a website pushed down on you.  If you want to read web pages, you'd want to be looking at the cache ..

Answer (score 0):

First let me rewrite your goal:
You want to read articles from a website which is now down.

You do not need cookies for this. And even if you found the cookies they would not contain the information you are looking for. The cookies are used to remember logins or settings. Think of it as a library card with your name on it. You want to read a book after a library got closed and you are asking to find the library card.

Now to find the actual old website content you have at least two options:

1. Look in Chrome's cache. For that please leave Chrome off. Do all your research from another browser in order not to push older information out of the cache. Use another browser and search for [chrome cache viewer](https://www.google.nl/search?q=chrome+cache+viewer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=LLexVrSfNIata63wp8gL) or similar. Note that I have no experience any of these.
2. Or search for a backup of the website. Your best bet for this seems to be the waybackmachine/ [Internet archive](http://archive.org/web/).